# Java read a text file 2 columns and store in array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I have a text file such as `"01/01/2011,14.25" "02/01/2011,16.78"` and many more rows.I would like to read and store in an array first column as string(to be plotted later on x axe)and second column as double.Columns separator could be comma,semicolon,space or tab.I have been able to read single column text file using FileReader and BufferedReader,but don't know how to do if I have two or more columns.I use Java and NetBeans.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1 Read whole row using `BufferedReader` `readLine()` method/
2 split String by your delimiter and have  string  array

for example

```
String str = "01/01/2011,14.25";
String arr[] = str.split(",");
//arr[0]; will hold date part and arr[1] will hold double part you can parst it to double using Double.parseDouble(string);
```

- [How to read file line by line](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/53.html)
- [String javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split)

Comment: @Jigar and @Vladimir,I am sure I didn't wrote correctly.My file looks like 01/01/2011,14.25 02/01/2011,16.78 03/01/2011,15.25 it is a matrix with comma separated columns.First column is date second one is double value.Number of file rows is (text.length). I would like to store these data in a bi-dimensional array[i][y].

Answer (score 1):

Read each line using buffered reader and then do that:

```
HashMap<String, Double> values = new HashMap<String, Double>;

// read the line here
String line = ...;
String strings[] = line.split(",");
values.put(strings[0], Double.valueOf(strings[1]);
```